# AWS-Amplify project-config.json' does not exist Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'am using AWS-Amplify to deploy my react app. When I use command `amplify publish` it gives this error.

I have tried below commands nothing solves my project issue

1 `amplify configure project`

2 `amplify init --appId [App Id]`

And when I tried `amplify env list` it gives below result

[image]